# Python: Randomly execute python functions with not random inner parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am creating a function that executes other functions randomly in a loop, but the difference between all other examples I have seen in Stack Overflow is that in this case, the parameters must be specific for every function.

For example: `func_a()` can only be executed with parameter `a`

```
import random    

def account(self, first_name, last_name, ID):
    random.choice([
                self.function_first_name(first_name),
                self.function_last_name(last_name),
                self.function_user_name(user_name)
            ])
```

In this case I am getting the execution in the same order all the time, it behaves like a loop, which is ok, but not random.

How can I keep it simple and execute all functions once but in random order

Comment: How about first generate a number from 0 to number of functions. then use a switch statement to execute the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create your list, you are actually calling and evaluating all three functions every time. Instead, you can zip the functions to their corresponding arguments, then randomly select one function & argument pair, then call that one only.

```
def account(self, first_name, last_name, ID):
    funcs = [self.function_first_name,
             self.function_last_name,
             self.function_user_name]
    args = [first_name, last_name, ID]
    fun, arg = random.choice(list(zip(funcs, args)))
    fun(arg)
```

Some examples

```
>>> p.account('bob', 'smith', 12345)
smith
>>> p.account('bob', 'smith', 12345)
bob
>>> p.account('bob', 'smith', 12345)
12345
>>> p.account('bob', 'smith', 12345)
smith
>>> p.account('bob', 'smith', 12345)
12345
```

If you want to call all of the functions, but in a random order you could do something like this

```
def account(self, first_name, last_name, ID):
    funcs = [self.function_first_name,
             self.function_last_name,
             self.function_user_name]
    args = [first_name, last_name, ID]
    pairs = list(zip(funcs, args))
    random.shuffle(pairs)
    for fun, arg in pairs:
        fun(arg)
```

Comment: This one is quite nice! How do I execute it in a loop? for fun, arg in  list(zip(funcs, args))??

Comment: What exactly do you want to loop? Do you want to do a `random.choice` for a certain `N` number of times?

Comment: If there are 3 functions, execute all of them in random order, but only once per function

Comment: In that case you can use `random.shuffle` to randomize your list of function/argument pairs, then just call each item in the shuffled list.